# Is there a solution to VIM netrw liststyle=3 causing <C-O> to misbehave?

Tags: vim

I like to set the netrw setting for list style to:

```
g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

And when I hop around within a file or to go back to the file explorer, I prefer `<C-O>` but if the netrw file explorer is in mode 3, `<C-O>` sometimes sends you back to an empty buffer with NetrwTreeListing 1 in the status bar and just stays there.  Other times if you hit return shortly after `<C-O>` it will show the file explorer (not always, however).  If I cycle in the file explorer with `i` to go to a different liststyle and open a file and then use `<C-O>`, it immediately takes me back to the file explorer without fail.

Is this a known bug? (I'm on OSX with VIM 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 14 2016 16:06:49))

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your vim and netrw.  Vim is up to 7.4.2118, so vim 7.3 is very old.  Netrw is up to v157h (http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).